# Qt 5.8: Workaround for QWebEngine not supporting static libraries

Tags: qt, deployment, static-libraries, qtwebengine

I'm trying to deploy an application using Qt 5.8 and need the following libraries:

- Qt5Core
- Qt5Gui
- Qt5Network
- Qt5Widgets
- Qt5WebEngineCore
- Qt5WebEngineWidgets

I originally wanted to create static libraries for all these and use those in my deployment but I read that QWebEngine does not support static libraries.

All I have to work with is the shared libraries.

Example:

```
$ ls -lrt libQt5WebEngineCore*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 95625576 Jan 18  2017 libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28 Mar 22 12:38 libQt5WebEngineCore.so -> libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28 Mar 22 12:38 libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.8 -> libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28 Mar 22 12:38 libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 -> libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.8.0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     1703 Mar 22 12:38 libQt5WebEngineCore.prl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     1226 Mar 22 12:38 libQt5WebEngineCore.la
```

Since I can't create a static library for QWebEngine is it ok to tar the shared library files with the -dereference option to preserve the softlinks in order to deploy to the user?

Comment: Well, it's just an opinion, by I think that it's a fair way to deploy. All those symlinks & other are only a Linux way to handle library dependencies regarding their versions.
More to say -- it's a common way to deploy all the shared library dependencies "as is", via dep packages or some other, multiple files shouldn't be a problem, after all.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware: make sure you do not violate Qt's license with static linking.

Comment: I'm just deploying an application that includes QWebEngine and need to figure out how to deploy. What's my best course of action as to not violate the Qt License? I need to deploy the libraries for the above list of Qt components in my post.